# Critical angle of attack at high altitude

Tags: aerodynamics, airfoil, angle-of-attack, high-altitude

I remember hearing somewhere that at very high altitudes, the critical angle of attack for a given airfoil can decrease a bit. Is there any credence to this idea?

Thank you

Comment: Good reference [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27693/how-does-the-ias-stall-speed-vary-with-increasing-altitude) two answers down.  Mach number (true airspeed) appears to effect airflow over the upper wing, hence a change in critical AoA with altitude (even though IAS is the same).