# Can we use the mobile phone GPS at 36,000 ft?

Tags: commercial-aviation, cell-phone

Is it possible to use the built-in GPS function via the smartphone at high altitude during flying as a flight crew ?

Comment: GNSS constellation satellites (Navstar, Glonass, Galileo, etc) orbit at 20,000 km altitude, you have some margin. There are unclear [legal constraints](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14687/current-situation-with-cocom-regulations-and-gps-receivers-for-balloons-and-cube) in altitude and speed set by US COCOM. You need to have a well designed receiver and be near a window if possible, to maximize the signal from the satellites, as what is true in a car is also true in an aircraft (metal blocks signals)

Comment: Questions about the experience of passengers on commercial flights (which I assume is what you're asking about here) are off-topic on this site. Also, I'm pretty sure this one has already been answered, either here or on [travel.se].

Comment: related, if not duplicate: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/42617/1467