# How do I calculate the wind angle relative to the aircraft's heading?

Tags: wind, heading

If I want to calculate the wind angle relative to the aicraft's heading, I use TAS and not IAS, right?

I want to calculate the relative wind angle to the aircraft. I have this information to work with: GS, IAS, TAS, Heading and GPS direction. I wonder if I can just calculate the ground vector (ground speed and direction) minus air vector (TAS and heading)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the real Ground Speed from True Air Speed?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43610/how-to-calculate-the-real-ground-speed-from-true-air-speed) You can rearrange the formula in the answers to find your wind speed and angle.

Comment: Does [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/35429/62) help? It seems to be the same.

Comment: Yes, sort of. Thank you